# I Need To Develop The Webservice By Using Saml And Wso2Is With Security

Tags: spring-security, wso2, saml-2.0, spring-saml, wso2-identity-server

I have two webservices, one is calling the other. I want to protect the first webservice by using the saml and wso2is. When I log in with the credientials of the wso2is the first webservice want to open and that webservice will want to call the other webservice.

Comment: I assume that you are referring single sign on scenario. If yes, you can get an idea from [Configuring Single Sign On with SAML 2.0]  [Configuring Single Sign On with SAML 2.0]: https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Configuring+Single+Sign-On+with+SAML+2.0

Comment: Thanku shashika, but that is not my requirement We were looking to use Apache CXF/Axis2 framework to implement REST services. We would like to provide federated access to the rest services via SAML. The identify provider will  be a rest service  and in the saml assertion the headers username and password has to come with the token                   Thanks,                                                                                                               vijay

Answer (score 0):

That is where Single Sign-On is acheived, you can refer [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/SAML+2.0+Web+SSO)